# get parameters when route is changed in root component using Angular2

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-ui-router

so i want to get parameters when route is changed in root component, i tried this :

```
export class AppComponent {
       constructor(_router: Router) {
         _router.events.subscribe((links) => {
        console.log("detection : ",links);
    });
    }
}
```

in the result i get links on each route change event for example :

```
deletection : "/product/1"
deletection : "/product/2"
```

**but i can't get the parameters values (1 and 2).**

i tested also the activateRoute width params but i got no result when route is changed.

Route file :

```
export const routes: Routes = [

    { path: "", component: LoginComponent },
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoggedOutGuard] },
    { path: "product/:id", component: ProductComponent, canActivate: [LoggedOutGuard] },

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Add your routes file please

Comment: Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to get parameters in the root component, when the route is changed

You can't. Why? Because your root component is not assigned to any route. Go to your **ProductComponent** and change it to something like this:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'product'
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You will notice that your product id will get logged in the console, why? Because your **ProductComponent** is assigned to the route `product/:id`, so basically your components can only get the route params of the routes they are assigned to.

The only way for your **AppComponent** know about the route params, is using a service to share that information. So your **ProductComponent** should talk to a **RouteParamsService** created by you.

Comment: so there is one solution is to get params using regex

Comment: i mean extract parametrs in root component constructor from links that i get from events.subscribe (...) using regex

Comment: You can only extract params on the Components that are assigned to that route

Comment: i think i can, just give me some minutes to show you :)

Comment: Oh you mean getting the full url and doing regex to figure it out? yes you can do that, but that doesn't scale and you probably will get a lot mismatches

Comment: yeah thats the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you....

```
constructor(private router:Router){
    router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            console.log("userName parameter in routing "+data['userName']);
        });
}
```

Comment: Property 'queryParams' does not exist on type 'RouterState'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```ts
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    this.route.params.forEach(params => {
      console.log(params)

    });
  }

  getParams(route) {
    let result = [];
    for(var key in route.snapshot.params) {
      var p = new Object();
      result.push(p[key] = route.snapshot.params[key]);
    }
    for(var r in route.children) {
      result = result.concate(this.getParams(r));
    }
    return result;
  }
```

*not tested*